# How to use abbrevs

Tags: abbrev

I find using abbrevs in Emacs confusing.  Despite [reading](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Defining-Abbrevs.html#Defining-Abbrevs) [the](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Expanding-Abbrevs.html#Expanding-Abbrevs) [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Editing-Abbrevs.html#Editing-Abbrevs) and the [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AbbrevMode), I continue to have problems using them.

**Goal**:

Define a quick, throw-away abbrev for a single Emacs session.

**Example:**

When using Python and Numpy, outputs are sometimes shortened with an ellipsis:

```
array(['1007.65', '1007.63', '1007.66', ..., '993.40', '993.40', '993.57'],
      dtype=object)
```

To display the array in full, you need to issue this mouthful of a statement:

```
with np.printoptions(threshold=np.inf): print(my_arr['field_name'])
```

This seems like a perfect situation for an abbrev!

Here's what I do:

1. Type `fp` for "full print"
2. With point immediately after `p` in `fp`, issue `C-x a g` (`add-global-abbrev`)
3. In the minibuffer prompt for `Global abbrev for "fp":`, put `with np.printoptions(threshold=np.inf): print()` and press `<RET>`
4. The minibuffer exits, returning me to my original buffer with point after `p` in `fp`
5. Issue `C-x a e` (`expand-abbrev`)

Nothing happens.

If I check `list-abbrevs`, there it is:

```
(global-abbrev-table)

"with np.printoptions(threshold=np.inf): print()" 0 "fp"
```

My understanding is that I don't need `abbrev-mode` enabled, as that's only used for automatic expansion.  Incidentally, enabling `abbrev-mode` still doesn't expand `fp`.

I'm at a loss for what I'm doing wrong and would appreciate some advice!

Comment: Since you read the Emacs doc about this but interpreted the behavior backward, please consider telling Emacs about the problem and perhaps suggest some different wording: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. It's likely that you are not the only person to have gotten this backward. Perhaps the doc should include an example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You defined your abbrev backwards - "with np.printoptions(threshold=np.inf): print()" will expand to "fp" with what you've done!

To define a multi-word abbrev, you should do:

1. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `define-global-abbrev`
2. `fp`
3. `with np.printoptions(threshold=np.inf): print()`

Answer (score 2):

What about

1. Put point immediately after p in fp.
2. Issue `C-x a i g` (inverse-add-global-abbrev).
3. Enter `with np.printoptions(threshold=np.inf): print()` and press RET.
4. `C-x a e`

BTW I have abbrev-mode switched on all the time and it almost always helps and almoste never gets in my way.